# Как лучше сверстать такой макет?

Tags: html, css

Как лучше сверстать такой макет?
Есть два вида макета - под монитор 1366 и 1920  (ну и дизайн резиновый, под другие тоже должно подстраиваться)

Проблема с блоком основного контента с акциями и товарами среди них. 
Т.е. я пока не могу понять как выстроить хтмл. Возможно ли без применения js плагинов?

[image: 1366]

[image: 1920]

в макете под 1920 блоков больше, так как в макете под 1366 просто предполагается что остальные блоки будут ниже по нарисованному принципу.

Comment: щас гриды достаточно хорошо поддерживаются и с ними проще чем с флоатами и гораздо легче настроить любую сетку ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно без JS, сейчас для такого писать JS - это уже изврат. Проще всего это сделать на гридах. Можно прописать media-query для 1366, в котором грид меняет позиции ячеек, и они могут скрывать или переходить в другие места. Также можно делать на флексах, но тогда придётся морочиться. Пока не ясно как конкретно перестраиваются ваши блоки, поэтому пример написать не получится.

Вот пример, на 800px перестроение происходит:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="grid">
   <div class="block block-blue">Пример блока синий</div>
   <div class="block block-red">Пример блока красный</div>
   <div class="block block-green">Пример блока зеленый</div>
   <div class="block block-gray">Пример блока серый</div>
   <div class="block block-viol">Пример блока фиолетовый</div>
  </div>
  
 </div>

 <style type="text/css">
  
  html, body, .container {
   height: 100%;
  }
  
  body {
   margin: 0;
  }
  
  .container {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 30px;
   height: 100%;
  }
  
  .grid {
   height: 100%;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-column-gap: 30px;
   grid-row-gap: 30px;
  }
  
  .block {
   background-color: silver;
  }
  
  .block-blue {
   background-color: #00a6ff;
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
  
  .block-red {
   background-color: #d2483b;
  }
  
  .block-green {
   background-color: #3c8e10;
   grid-column: 2 / 4;
   grid-row: 2 / 4;
  }
  
  .block-viol {
   background-color: mediumpurple;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px){
   
   .block-red {
    grid-column: 0 / 1;
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
   }
   
   .block-gray {
    display: none;
   }
   
  }
  
 </style>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Гридами еще не пользовался.. все еще считал что у них пока недостаточная поддерживаемость.. Конкретность перестраиваемости не обсуждалась, так что порядок произволен.
Если не сложно, буду благодарен примеру :)

Comment: Процентов 95 будет поддержка если отбросить IE, который уже никому не нужен. И условия про старые браузеры не было. Если у вас только современные нужно поддерживать, то время грида уже давно пришло.

Comment: Можете на флексах писать, если старое нужно. Во флексах тоже можно менять позиции блоков, задавая им номер позиции. Но у гридов можно задавать номер ячейки или название, а не просто индекс, что существенно упрощает задачу.

Comment: Плюс можно деградацию написать, если гриды у браузера не работают. И сделать все блоки просто на всю ширину например.

Comment: ну желательна большая поддерживаемость. Ок, спасибо! буду пробовать флексами)

Comment: и спасибо за пример с гридами :)